# How to get a Vue b-table to scroll the body with a fixed header

Tags: html, css, vue.js, vuejs2, bootstrap-vue

I've got a `b-table` element on a page that currently displays a bunch of data from a database. At the moment it is paginated, but feedback has indicated that they would rather have all the information displayed in a single scrolling view. I can do this, but the problem is that if I set a containing `div` to scroll the whole table, it also scrolls the column headers away. I need to find a way to be able to scroll just the table body while leaving the column headers in place, and I'd prefer to be able to do it within the bounds of the element itself instead of rigging up something with completely separate header and body with a bunch of Javascript rigging in the background.

Under the component reference of the [bootstrap-vue table component](https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/docs/components/table#component-reference), it says that there is a property called `tbody-class` which looks like it's a way to specify a custom class for the tbody (crazily enough). The page doesn't give any indication of how to use it, though, and my experimentation hasn't produced any results:

```
<b-table 
    tbody-class="my-class"   <- Applies prop to table but not to tbody
    :tbody-class="my-class"  <- Seemingly ignored entirely
>
```

It sounds like this sort of issue was solved on [this issue thread](https://github.com/bootstrap-vue/bootstrap-vue/issues/1405), but it doesn't really detail *how* it was solved. It mentions that the functionality was added to "the next update", but neither the patch notes of the version released following that comment nor the documentation mentions that addition at all (unless it means the properties I mentioned in the previous paragraph). It does talk about using CSS selectors to apply the style in a roundabout fashion, but I wasn't able to get that to work either. (In the following example, the `tbody` in the Chrome inspector did not have the applied style.)

```
.table.my-table > tbody {
    height: 100px;
}
```

The version of Vue I'm using is 2.2.6.

Comment: Ugh, playing with [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/a5s95a3q/195/), the table just ignores any CSS you put on it.

Comment: have you tried `:tbody-class="'my-class'"` or `:tbody-class="['my-class']"` ? It expects tbody-class to be `String or Array`

Comment: @JacobGoh `:tbody-class="'my-class'"` and `:tbody-class="['my-class']"` both seem to just be interpreted as `:tbody-class="my-class"`. If I add another element like `:tbody-class="['my-class','my-other-class']"`, then _that_ seems to just turn into `:tbody-class="my-class,my-other-class"`. I think that's just what it means by a "String or Array".

Comment: *(I can't post comments so here's an answer)* Fixed headers are useful when scrolling down a table that's longer than the page. Boot-strap tables offer a way to avoid scrolling down altogether: [pagination](https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/docs/components/table/#pagination). This doesn't answer the question but it may solve the problem (it did to me).

Comment: @fredericf The second sentence indicates that pagination is not a desired option.

Comment: Seems like working: https://jsfiddle.net/guyzLpsk (latest `bootstrap-vue`).

Answer (score 4):

Since [v2.0.0-rc.28](https://github.com/bootstrap-vue/bootstrap-vue/releases/tag/v2.0.0-rc.28), optional props [`sticky-header`](https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/docs/components/table/#sticky-headers) has been added to support fixed headers.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    items: [
      { heading1: 'table cell', heading2: 'table cell', heading3: 'table cell' },
      { heading1: 'table cell', heading2: 'table cell', heading3: 'table cell' },
      { heading1: 'table cell', heading2: 'table cell', heading3: 'table cell' },
      { heading1: 'table cell', heading2: 'table cell', heading3: 'table cell' },
      { heading1: 'table cell', heading2: 'table cell', heading3: 'table cell' },
      { heading1: 'table cell', heading2: 'table cell', heading3: 'table cell' },
      { heading1: 'table cell', heading2: 'table cell', heading3: 'table cell' },
      { heading1: 'table cell', heading2: 'table cell', heading3: 'table cell' },
      { heading1: 'table cell', heading2: 'table cell', heading3: 'table cell' },
      { heading1: 'table cell', heading2: 'table cell', heading3: 'table cell' },
      { heading1: 'table cell', heading2: 'table cell', heading3: 'table cell' },
      { heading1: 'table cell', heading2: 'table cell', heading3: 'table cell' }
    ],
  }
});
```

```html
<html>

<header>
  <script src="//unpkg.com/vue@2.6.11/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
  <script src="//unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@2.0.0/dist/bootstrap-vue.js"></script>

  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="//unpkg.com/bootstrap@4.3.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="//unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@2.0.0/dist/bootstrap-vue.min.css" />
</header>

<body>
  <div id="app">
    <b-table sticky-header :items="items" head-variant="light"></b-table>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

> I need to find a way to be able to scroll just the table body while leaving the column headers in place, and I'd prefer to be able to do it within the bounds of the element itself instead of rigging up something with completely separate header and body with a bunch of Javascript rigging in the background

I made an [example repository](https://github.com/jtlindsey/BootstrapVueFixedHeaderWithHiddenScroll) for you to see how to make it work (also has hidden scrollbar).

There are probably other ways to accomplish the same thing, but this is what I did.

```
<!-- wrap table in container with class. -->
    <b-container fluid class="table-container">
      <b-table
        :items="items" 
        :fields="fields" 
        caption-top
      >
      </b-table>
    </b-container>
```

And here is the CSS with hidden scrollbar.

```
.table-container {
     height: calc(100vh - 450px);
}
 .table-container table {
     display: flex;
     flex-flow: column;
     height: 100%;
     width: 100%;
}
 .table-container table thead {
     flex: 0 0 auto;
     width: 100%;
}
 .table-container table tbody {
     flex: 1 1 auto;
     display: block;
     width: 100%;
     overflow-y: auto;
}
 .table-container table tbody tr {
     width: 100%;
}
 .table-container table thead, .table-container table tbody tr {
     display: table;
     table-layout: fixed;
}
 .table-container table {
     border-collapse: collapse;
}
 .table-container table td, .table-container table th {
     padding: 0.4em;
}
 .table-container table th {
     border: 1px solid black;
     font-size: 0.7vw;
}
 .table-container table td {
     border: 1px solid #e7e1e1;
     font-size: 0.85em;
    /* necessary to set for proper "showing row x of y" calculations if infinate scoll */
     white-space: nowrap;
     text-align: center;
     padding: 10px 5px;
     white-space: nowrap;
     text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
 .table-container table thead {
     border: 2px solid #0F0FA3;
}
 .table-container th {
     background-color: #0F0FA3;
     color: #b5aba4;
     cursor: pointer;
     -webkit-user-select: none;
   -moz-user-select: none !important;
     -ms-user-select: none;
     user-select: none;
}
 .table-container table tbody td {
     padding: 8px;
     cursor: pointer;
}
 .table-container table tbody tr:hover {
     background-color: rgba(168, 168, 239, .5);
}
 .table-container table thead td {
     padding: 10px 5px;
}
 .table-container tr:nth-child(even) {
     background-color: rgba(168, 168, 239, 1);
}

/* START Adjustments for width and scrollbar hidden */
 .table-container th.table-action, .table-container td.table-action {
     width: 5.8vw;
}
 .table-container table thead {
     width: calc(100% - 1px);
}
 .table-container table tbody::-webkit-scrollbar {
     width: 1px;
}
 .table-container table tbody::-webkit-scrollbar {
     width: 1px;
}
 .table-container table tbody::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
     width: 1px;
}
/* END Adjustments for width and scrollbar */
```

Update, another way to have fixed header but very restricted ([ref](https://github.com/bootstrap-vue/bootstrap-vue/issues/2777#issuecomment-469915250)):

> There are a few ways you can do this... and cross browser is not
>   always guaranteed:
>
> create a class, say, my-table-scroll

```
table.my-table-scroll,
table.my-table-scroll > thead,
table.my-table-scroll > tbody,
table.my-table-scroll > tfoot,
table.my-table-scroll > tbody > tr,
table.my-table-scroll > thead > tr {
  width: 100%;
  display: block
}
table.my-table-scroll > thead,
table.my-table-scroll > tbody,
table.my-table-scroll > tfoot {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
table.my-table-scroll > thead,
table.my-table-scroll > tfoot {
  height: auto;
}
/* these last two rules you will need to tweak on an as needed basis */
table.my-table-scroll > tbody {
  /* set max height for tbody before it scrolls */
  max-height: 200px;
}
table.my-table-scroll > thead > tr > th,
table.my-table-scroll > thead > tr > td,
table.my-table-scroll > tbody > tr > th,
table.my-table-scroll > tbody > tr > td,
table.my-table-scroll > tfoot > tr > th,
table.my-table-scroll > tfoot > tr > td {
  display: inline-block;
  /* you need to explicitly specify the width of the table cells */
  /* either equal, or specify individual widths based on col index. */
  /* Here, we assume you have 4 columns of data */
  width: 25%;
}
/*
  could use sibling selectors to select specific columns for widths:
  td + td (second column)
  td + td + td (3rd column, etc)
*/
```

> And then place the class onto your b-table.